# Problem Analysis - Answer but no procedure - Finding Trajectories.

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving

I stumbled with this problem in a notebook that has been bothering for the whole day(actually 3)...The answer is written but there's no explanation nor a steb-by-step procedure or anything. If you know how to analyse the problem and create an equation from this, I will be very grateful!

Find the ortogonal trajectories at the cissoid :

$(2a-x) y^2 = x^3$

Answer: $(x^2 + y^2) = C(2x^2 + 2y^2)$

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

if you difference $(2a - x)y^2 = x^3$ you get the tangent to the cissoid satisfies
$$(2a-x)2y\, dy -(y^2 + 3x^2) \, dx = 0 .$$ therefore, the normal to the cissoid satisfies the differential equation 
$$(2a-x)2y\, dy + (y^2 + 3x^2) \, dx = 0 .$$

we can write it as a system two differential equations $$\frac{dx}{dt} = x - 2a, \frac{d(y^2)}{dt} = y^2 + 3x^2.$$ we can solve these as 
$$x = 2a+ Ce^t,  y^2 = De^t + 3\left(4a^2 + 2aC\,  te^t + C^2 e^{2t}\right)$$

we can eliminate the $t$ between the $x$ and $y$ to get the family of normal curves to the cissoid

$$ y^2 = \frac{D}{C}(x-2a) + 3\left(4a^2 + 2a(x-2a)\ln(\frac{x-2a}{C}) + (x-2a)^2\right) $$

this is much more more complicated than the one you have. i hope i have not made any errors.

Comment: the book is machine typed so Im guessing the answer I have is correct.
I have 2 questions tho.... What does De^t mean? and how did we know the normal? and that it satisfies?

Comment: @Rodrigo, $2x+3y = A$ is normal(orthogonal) to $3x-2y = B$ for all $A, B.$  and $De^t$ means the product of $D$ and $e^t$ because a solution to $\frac{dy}{dt} = y$ is $y = De^t.$

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I don't know if you did something wrong or not but I think it is a little bit clear of what you did. So you just made dx/dy on the first equation? And where did you get A and B?

Btw, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Rodrigo, if two curves are orthogonal to each other at $(x,y)$ then their slopes must be like $2dx + 3dy = A$ and $3dx - 2dy = B.$  i am using $2$ and $3$ but they can be more complicated as in your example. do you have a text book from where you got this question. it will help you if read and redo some problems similar to but easier problem.